# Adding carriage returns in a format string

Tags: cocoa-touch, email, string-formatting

I am trying to get Carriage returns after each string in my email body.  I am drawing a blank.

This is the code I’m using at the moment:

```
- (IBAction)mailButtonPressed {
    MFMailComposeViewController *controller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    controller.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [controller setSubject:@"Pressed Data..."];

    appDelegate= (TemplateIponeAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;

    NSString *MessageBody=[NSString stringWithFormat:@" Hi: %@ F Result: %d , R Result: %d , B Result: %d,  P Result: %d......... total Reults: %d   total time :%@",clientName.text, appDelegate.FCount,appDelegate.RCount,appDelegate.BCount,appDelegate.PCount,appDelegate.TotalPressed,appDelegate.time];

    [controller setMessageBody:MessageBody isHTML:NO];
    [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
    [controller release];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a `\n` in your format string wherever you want a new line.

Comment: In an email message, it should probably be `\r\n`, for CR LF.

Comment: There is another important key in here... cause I've been looking for this online for an hour. It HAS to be isHTML:NO.  YES and it will strip out the \n's.